# htaccess for an mvc framework to allow www

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been researching htaccess and learning quite a bit about it, but I'm still stuck on a very specific requirement we have. Actually there are 2 requirements, but one of them is critical while the other one is a "would be very nice."

Question 1: What is the best way to write my htaccess file for an MLM site written on MVC framework that would allow users to type www.mlmsiteaddress.org/aff/affiliatename when the site does not accept www?

Background: This software allows inserting new members, then provides that new member with a URL for which their affiliate identifier, email, phone number, address, etc show up on the banner and underneath which is a "squeeze page," or very simple opt-in form which brings in new leads to the company and other things that happen after this form submits don't have any bearing on this question.

Problem: When users click a link, or type in manually, the URL www.mlmsiteaddres.org/aff/affiliatename, it does not display the affiliate banner info. Instead, it shows just the corporate banner, which is the default affiliate in case the user had attempted to navigate to an inactive affiliate's site. For some reason this wasn't an issue before but has recently become an issue, shortly after I cleaned up a BLACOLE/JS virus off the site. From what I can ascertain, the htaccess file we are using now is identical to how it came to us from the software vendor.

Normal Behavior: Previously, the www portion of the URL was being simply ignored, and the site was loading http://mlmsiteaddress.org in the url for each affiliate site. So, even though the affiliate  banner information would show up, the affiliate name would not populate in the URL. Which brings me to...

Question 2: How can I force the URL to display the affiliate username in the banner when on an affiliate page using htaccess?

Question 3: Is htaccess the only way to do these things (assuming both of these are possible)? I have some basic working knowledge of it but am no expert, though I'll have a far richer understanding once I solve this problem!

Here is the htaccess that is currently being used (which came with the mlm software "out of the box" so to speak).

```
<Files ~ "serial.txt$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^aff/(.*)$ /index.php/aff/?aff=$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, connecting to http://www.mlmsiteaddress.org doesn't work but http://mlmsiteaddress.org does. In that case, you can force a redirection if the site isn't accessed via http://mlmsiteaddress.org (using www, or any other subdomain):

```
<Files ~ "serial.txt$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mlmsiteaddress\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://mlmsiteaddress.org/$1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^aff/(.*)$ /index.php/aff/?aff=$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: I am so sorry I have delayed so long in responding to this. I saw your response immediately and was so happy to get some qualified help with this, but have not been able to put it to the test yet. I actually screwed it up even more somehow, though I restored the original htaccess file, the url is still showing up now as http://mlmsiteaddress.org/index.php/home/pdirectory/public_html/http::/mlmsiteaddress.org/

Comment: The issue is that when users type in www.mlmsiteaddress.org, they automatically get http://mlmsiteaddress.org. And when they go to www.mlmsiteaddress.org/aff/affiliatename, it just goes to http://mlmsiteaddress.org and does not load an affiliate banner. But if they go to http://mlmsiteaddress.org/aff/affiliatename, it does load the affiliate banner correctly. I need to make this site such that people can enter the www (as they are wont to do, regardless of any instructions to the contrary), they are still navigating to the correct place, and I'm familiar but not expert on MVC framework.

Comment: Just re-read my first comment which doesn't make much sense. I tried a variation of the solution you posted, which caused the URL to read as I mentioned above. I tried the posted solution, which did the same thing. I replaced the htaccess with the original htaccess contents, but it is still redirecting as mentioned above. I will look at the controller file.

Comment: The 3 lines I added should only redirect to your root domain and keep everything after the /, so typing www.mlmsiteaddress.org redirects to mlmsiteaddress.org, and typing www.mlmsiteaddress.org/aff/affiliatename redirects to mlmsiteaddress.org/aff/affiliatename, which will redirect to mlmsiteaddress.org/index.php/aff/?aff=affiliatename. Isn't it what you want ?

Comment: that's exactly what I want, but for some reason the url is showing up like so when I go to www.mlmsiteaddress.org/aff/affiliatename:  http://mlmsiteaddress.org/index.php/home/pdirectory/public_html/http::/mlmsiteaddress.org/  ... which returns an mvc error that the controller method doesn't exist. I am now inspecting the controller file a bit closer to see if I can ascertain anything there, though I doubt it because I'm the only person who edits that file, and it hasn't been edited since I removed the blacole kit from the site last month.

Comment: oh the whole link didn't show up. It's http:// mlmsiteaddress.org/index.php/home/pdirectory/public_html/http::/ mlmsiteaddress.org

Comment: Once the corrupted file was cleaned out, this htaccess did exactly what it was intended to do. Sorry for all the ramblings, I got overwhelmed. Thank you for your help.